# A "google docs" for flow charts?

Tags: collaboration, workflow

I have a project that requires many people working together on a large flowchart with a few thousand entries. There are many flowchart software (or website) out there but is there any that allows you to work together as a group like google docs does without having to save and send updated copies to everyone every time someone makes an edit? Also, preferably free.

Answer (score 1):

Did you test the Google Docs "Draw" app yet? It also supports creating flow charts.

Comment: Looks ok, but I am looking for something with a large blank canvas. It will be very difficult for the chart to be fit on a page.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.lucidchart.com/ has a good colloborative offering. They have a free version, but limited. They also allow you to connect it to Google Drive.

Comment: It's good but remember I need 1000s of entries. Thanks anyway.